# C Matrix Program

Tags: c, matrix, symmetric

I have a matrix program that so far takes an input file in and expresses the numbers in matrices. I also wrote a function to find its transpose but I can't figure out how to do the symmetrical.

I have to take only 3 input parameters (MainMatrix[max][max] MainTranspose[max][max] and the Size)

It should return -1 if it isn't symmetrical and 0 if it is.

My program shows everything right except for 1 that says it is not symmetrical when it SHOULD be.

I hope one of you guys can help me with this.

```
int Symmetry (int mainmatrix[max][max], int maintranspose[max][max], int size) {
    double thesqrtSize = sqrt((double)Size);
    double fract = thesqrtSize - floor(thesqrtSize);
    if(fract > 0.0001) 
        return -1;
    int isqrtSize = (int)thesqrtSize;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<isqrtSize;i++){
        for(j=0;j<isqrtSize;j++) {
            if(mainmatrix[i][j]!=maintranspose[i][j]) {
                return -1; 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Show us THE CODE

Comment: put some effort, add code..

Comment: Can't really help you if we don't have the code and the failing test case.

Comment: I like how within half a minute there were three people going GIVE US THE CODE BWARGH.

Comment: Though if you have the matrix and the transpose, wouldn't it just be a simple matter of comparing each element?

Comment: Okay, sorry. One second.

Comment: I have added it, sorry about that.

Comment: yes as you can see, i tried to compare them and when i output it, i get one of the matrices that isn't right; it says its not symmetrical but it is.

Comment: The matrices you compare `if(Mat[i][j]!=Transp[i][j]) {` are not the matrices you pass in: `int Symmetry (int mainmatrix[max][max], int maintranspose[max][max], int size)`.

Comment: right, i changed that and still same output.

Comment: Also, `max` must be a compile-time constant for that to compile. If your arguments don't have `max` columns, the access will be wrong (you're then getting undefined behaviour). Can you post a bit more of the code, so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: "if it isn't symmetrical and 0 if it is." You check the 2 matrices for equality. Are You sure You want to do this? You don't need to transopse the matrix to find if it is symmetrical. You can do it by checking  `mainmatrix[i][j]!=mainmatrix[j][i]`

Comment: Right, but the parameter of the transpose is required to compare the two

Comment: You don't need to compare it with the transpose. You can check it without the transpose. I've just suggested an easier way to solve this.

Comment: Vague title is not going to be useful to future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are notoriously prone to rounding errors. And if the result of sqrt is just a little bit below the intended result, the call to `floor` will make it off by (almost) 1. Try adding 1 to size before taking the square root. This is safe and will guarantee a correct result provided size is a square number.

The suggested change:

```
double thesqrtSize = sqrt((double)(Size+1));
```

Obviously this means your method of using `floor` to check for squareness won't work. I suggest casting to int, squaring, and comparing to the original size to see if they're the same.

Comment: Which line are you talking about that I should add it?

Comment: For reasonably small sizes, if `Size` is a square, the computed square root will be exact in all usual hardware.

Comment: Wow that worked for the one that was showing the incorrect output but I have a single number (14) in the matrix and the transpose of that is also 14 but that isn't showing it's symmetrical. I am assuming it is since the matrix=transpose.

Comment: @DavisApanasova maybe `Size` is not equal to `size`. how comes size and Size from?

Comment: Only one `size` is declared, but I think the asker typed his code in here rather than copypasting it, and that's why the case is all over the place.

Comment: Of course if there is a global variable named `Size` somewhere, that would explain a whole lot. As a side note, who here wants to see case sensitivity burnt at the stake? :D

Comment: Not only that. When assinging value to `fract`, there's a mysterious `sqrtSize`. That must be `thesqrtSize`.

Comment: Size = size ( i just wrote it fast. i also edited the code, sorry about the confusion guys)

Answer (score 0):

Symmetry function doesn't need the transpose matrix. You can find the answer without it:

```
int Symmetry (int mainmatrix[max][max], int size) {
    int isqrtSize= (int)sqrt((double)size);
    if(isqrtSize*isqrtSize!=size) 
        return -1;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<isqrtSize;i++){
        for(j=0;j<isqrtSize;j++) {
            if(mainmatrix[i][j]!=mainmatrix[j][i]) {
                return -1; 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

You didn't solve the multidimensional array parameter thing in the most elegant way, but lets use this. I think your program might work on this way:

- you declare a matrix with the maximum size
- You fill the upper left corner of the matrix and check for symmetricity
- `symmetry` method gets the entire matrix and try to figure out the dimensions and check the symmetry.

Now please see [THIS CODE](http://ideone.com/puJkra). I wrote a simple main function for this. As You can see, it works. So the problem should be at the method that generates the transpose matrix or with the given size in your program.

Another problem with the algorithm: You can not find dimensions from the number of the element. A matrix of 8*2 contains 16 element, so the method will see and handle it like it was a 4*4 matrix. If there are no cases like that, You can use the code above.

But: When you call the symmetry function, You compute the size as `size=rows*columns`, so You must know the sizes of the matrix. This means, You can simple give them to your function too. In this case, You don't have to do compute sqrt and other floating point values, You only have to check the input parameters if they are equal. With this, the function will look like this:

```
int Symmetry (int mainmatrix[max][max], int rows, int cols) {
    if(rows!=cols)
        return -1;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++) {
            if(mainmatrix[i][j]!=mainmatrix[j][i]) {
                return -1; 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference since you could compare either the main or the transpose (just switch the i and j variables). I'm not sure why one of the matrices that has the number 14 says "Not symmetrical" even though it should?

Comment: @DavisApanasova I edited the code. This check for perfect squares should also work if the input `size` is correct.

Comment: now another matrix says its not symmetrical when it is. :(

There is something very wrong going on but can't figure out what the cause is

Comment: @DavisApanasova Did you tried this or the one with the transpose? In the second case change one of the return statements to `return -2;` to see where the incorrect answer comes from. And write `size` to output to see if it is incorrect.

Comment: I tried this one.

So return -2 right after the if statement comparing the main matrix ?

Comment: I just tried that as well, it doesn't show anything. I get all of the correst responses (if they are symmetric then it says symmetric if not then it says not symmetric) except for just one of them.

Comment: Check the value returned by the function. And please copy-paste to your question the part where you call the function.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, what do you mean check the value returned by the function? How would I check that?

Comment: Please paste Your entire code, and I can help You more. It is hard to help when the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: Main has this:    r * c = rows*columns

int ret = Symm(mainmatrix, maintranspose, r*c);
     if(retrnvalue == 0) {
  printf("Is symmetrical.\n");
  }
  if(retrnvalue == -1) {
  printf("Is not symmetrical.\n");
  }

Comment: This can not call my function. So: 
1: copy your ENTIRE code(Ctrl+C) 
2: Click Edit your question, paste the code and format it with Ctrl+K

Comment: @DavisApanasova I edited the answer, please check it

Comment: @DavisApanasova When you ask a question(at every question) and get a good,helpful answer, You should upvote/accept it. Not neccessary mine.